# google map : get radius of circle overlay while creating circle

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am creating a web application that uses maps. on map I'm creating circle and want to show the radius in a div. I'm able to show radius after finishing the radius with overlay complete event. but i want to show the radius in a div while creating the circle to allow user to draw the circle with radius of their own length. Is there a way to do it. plz help me on this. Any feedback and help would be welcome and appreciated.
thanx in advance.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(e) {
        deleteSelectedShape();
        selectedShape = e.overlay;

       //selectedShape.setEditable(true);
      //overlayClickListener(selectedShape);

       if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE) {
            var bound = e.overlay.getBounds();
            bounds = bound;
            var radius = e.overlay.getRadius();
            radius = (radius/1000);
            $('#radius_size').html("Radius "+Math.round(radius)+" Km");

        } 
        else if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE) {
               deleteSelectedShape();
               var bound = e.overlay.getBounds();
               map.fitBounds(bound);

        }
```

Comment: The DrawingManager class only has event listener for when shapes have been completed, not while they're being dragged out. I thought you'd maybe be able to use something like mouse events on the map such as click and drag, but according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer) _"google.maps.Map events, such as click and mousemove are disabled while drawing on the map"_

Comment: Event with a standard shape, you don't have events that let you get the radius while editing the shape. You have a `radius_changed` event but it will only fire when you release your mouse / have finished editing. Other mouse events will not be triggered when editing the shape. Even using a timing function, I can't seem to be able to get the cricle radius while editing the shape.

Comment: * Even with a standard shape...

Answer (score 1):

See [this example in the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/articles/mvcfun/step6) from the "article" [Fun with MVC Objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/mvcfun), if you display the radius when the circle is created (in this example by adding `displayInfo(distanceWidget)` to the init function):

```
function init() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.790234970864, -122.39031314844),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var distanceWidget = new DistanceWidget(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'distance_changed', function () {
        displayInfo(distanceWidget);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(distanceWidget, 'position_changed', function () {
        displayInfo(distanceWidget);
    });
    displayInfo(distanceWidget);
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t49wg7f3/1/)